# Getting the formatting right with sprintf()

Tags: c, io, printf, code-composer

I'm trying to get some formatting done in my sprintf statement, but it doesn't seem to work as I expect. Here is the line:

```
n = sprintf(buffer, "x = %d.%d, y = %d.%d, z = %d.%d \n", x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2);
```

In that printout x1 is the whole part of the number, and x2 is the fractional part. All would be well, except I need to pad x2, y2, and z2 to always be 2 digits - meaning I need to pad with leading zeros.

With examples that I see online it seems like doing this should work:

```
n = sprintf(buffer, "x = %d.%02d, y = %d.%02d, z = %d.%02d \n", x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2);
```

However, that instead produces something like this:

```
x = 2.2d, y = 37.2d, z = 2.2d
```

The 37 above is actually x2, and it apparently got shifted over in place of y1. I tried putting brackets around the '02', but that doesn't do anything either.

I have tried splitting up the period too like this: (but that didn't work)

```
   n = sprintf(buffer, "x = %d. %02d, y = %d. %02d, z = %d. %02d \n", x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2);
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong... I'd appreciate any help. This isn't particularly vital to do in sprintf (I could theoretically write some 'if' statements and get it working that way), but it'd be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Works correctly here. Have you perhaps typed `O` instead of `0` in the conversions accidentally? [Far-fetched, I know]

Comment: @DanielFischer, well those are copy pasted from my code, and I think they're 0s. I checked again though :P I kind of hacked together a quick replacement function for this, but I'd be curious to know why this doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Okay, if that's a copy-paste, your format is correct. It worked copy-pasted from here, as visual inspection said it should. So, what compiler (and library implementation) are you using? It looks as if it doesn't implement all flags. Out of curiosity, what does it do with `%d.%2d`? Does it space-pad?

Comment: The %d.%2d gives me `x = -3.d, y = 59.d, z = -7.d`, moving x2 over again. (This is acceleration I'm actually measuring, but I know roughly what values should be where).
The compiler I have is TI v4.1.5 from Code Composer Studio 5. I have no idea how to check the library implementation :( Looking [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Printf_support_in_compiler) though it seems that there is an option to turn on full printf() support, which is supposed to be the default. I can't quite figure it out right now, but I'm looking.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that one in the least, sorry. But it definitely looks like you have only very limited `printf` support.

Comment: The "note" does say, *For MSP430, when creating new projects in CCS v4, this option is set to "minimal" by default to avoid large RAM requirements*. The "minimal" support eschews width and precision flags which would be consistent with the output you're seeing. Try `--printf_support=nofloat` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code and output.

```
float x1 = 10.12222;
float y1 = 20.23333;
float z1 = 30.34444;
int   xi = 10;
int   yi = 20;
int   zi = 30;
int   x0 = 5;
int   y0 = 5;
int   z0 = 5;
int   xl = 10;
int   yl = 10;
int   zl = 10;
char  chr[512];

printf("x = %5.2f, y = %5.2f, z = %5.2f\n", x1, y1, z1);
printf("x = %10d, y = %10d, z = %10d\n", xi, yi, zi);
printf("x = %010d, y = %010d, z = %010d\n", xi, yi, zi);
printf("x = %-10d, y = %-10d, z = %-10d\n", xi, yi, zi);
printf("x = %10.5d, y = %10.5d, z = %10.5d\n", xi, yi, zi); // DYNAMIC

/* Dynamic formatting of DYNAMIC commented line*/
sprintf(chr, "Dynamic: x = %%%d.%dd, y = %%%d.%dd, z = %%%d.%dd\n",
        xl, x0, yl, y0, zl, z0);
printf(chr, xi, yi, zi);
```

The output will be like this.

```
x = 10.12, y = 20.23, z = 30.34
x =         10, y =         20, z =         30
x = 0000000010, y = 0000000020, z = 0000000030
x = 10        , y = 20        , z = 30
x =      00010, y =      00020, z =      00030
Dynamic: x =      00010, y =      00020, z =      00030
```

%x.yd means,

x - Total characters for the integer.

y - Padding with 0s within that length.

%10.5d will give following results for 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 100000

```
bbbbbbbbbb => Spaces
     00010
     00100
     01000
     10000
    100000
   1000000
```

I hope this helps for your formatting.